# POI Excel chart - set property to - 'Don't move or size with cells'

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel template which has the table and charts already setup, just need to add data. There is a collapsible table (using group row) which has a variable number of rows. Beneath this table are two bar charts at the same vertical level.

After filling the table data the two charts are shifted down so when the table is expanded there is no overlapping between the table and charts.

To enable this the chart properties are set to 'Move but dont size with cells'. This works but when any columns or rows are resized the two charts start to move. **This can be fixed by using the 'Dont move or size with cells' option.**

[image]

I have tried the below code but am getting NPE with the following code. The `getGraphicFrame()` returns null.

`dbSheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getCharts().get(0).getGraphicFrame().getAnchor().setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);`

Can someone advise how this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: If the `getGraphicFrame()` returns null, then the chart is not within a graphic frame. Maybe it is within a chart sheet? But then setting 'Don't move or size with cells' option is useless at all. We would need the Excel document in question to be able to help.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thx for the explanation. I am unable to share the template in its current form, will have to recreate a similar excel. The template has been created manually is that the reason the chart is not within a graphic frame or is my assumption incorrect.

Comment: Well, you have a problem with a workbook and code you have created. To be able to help, one will need that workbook and that code. In other words one need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Else all answers only are guesses and no valid answers are possible. So without that minimal, reproducible example all attempts to answer will be waste of time only.